# Camera calibration in opencv - objectpoints

Tags: opencv, chess, camera-calibration

I have calibration working fine with calibratecamera, using a chessboard pattern.
Just wondering how to populate the 'objectpoints' vector. Do I use my chessboard dimensions in
mm or cm?

Answer (score 0):

The object points are in arbitrary units.  People often use the length of a chess square side as the unit but you can use whatever you like.

The camera calibration coefficients that are returned relate image position measured in *pixels* to the physical image position measured as the *tangent of an angle*.  Thus nothing in the results depends on the chessboard's physical size, whether measured in mm, cm, or inches.  This should make sense when you realize that you don't have to input distance between camera and target.  You can read more about this in the OpenCV docs [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.1/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).